# What does the def line do in python

Tags: python

What does the second to last line do here? It doesn't seem to be assigning a variable, printing or anything but I've tried breaking the code in various ways and the line `doublelist(somelist)` seems to be necessary but I don't know why.

```
def doubleList(list):
    i=0
    while i<len(list):
        list[i]=list[i]*2
        i=i+1

someList=[34,72,96]
doubleList(someList)
print someList
```

Comment: It modifies the list to change every item to its double. What's surprising about it?

Comment: It calls that function `def doubleList(list)`, which modifies `someList`. I suggest reading the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: `doubleList` modifies the list that's passed into it. Using horrible style.

Comment: Hey downvoters and closers, this is a legit beginner question.  Be kind to the newbie

Comment: you should not name your variables like any of the [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) or [types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) (e.g., `list`). This could have nasty side-effects as Python will not warn you for doing that!

Comment: Look at the first example on [Defining functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (Python tutorial).

Comment: Ok folks, we all started somewhere. Go flag some posts with real problems such as those with no effort, code samples, plz-send-teh-codes etc.

Comment: Hi guys this is just part of a tutorial I've been reading, sorry for the simplicity! Thanks for the links, I get it now :)

Comment: @ZCJ: run away from that tutorial as fast as possible. Whoever wrote that code doesn't know Python, and learning it from them would be a horrible mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can modify mutable arguments passed to them.  The (poorly-named) list called "list" has (using a non-idiomatic style) each of its elements multiplied by two, *in-place*.  For example:

```
>>> def inplace(seq):
...     seq[0] = 5
... 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> inplace(a)
>>> a
[5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
def doublieList(list):
```

and the following indented lines just create a function

The next-to-last line causes that function to be invoked on `someList`

Answer (score 1):

Since @DSM answered this question already, I'll supply a more pythonic version of this function:

```
    def doubleList(something_other_than_list):
        for i in range(len(something_other_than_list)): something_other_than_list[i] *= 2
```

Comment: Wouldn't `def doubleList(seq): seq[:] = [x*2 for x in seq]` be even more pythonic?

Comment: It would be better to choose a meaningful name `def doubleList(listOfNumbers): listOfNumbers[:] = [x*2 for x in listOfNumbers]` Names come from the problem domain where the word 'list' is understood to be a sequence.